# Buffer View With SpatiaLite and QGIS

Tags: qgis, buffer, spatialite

Creating a dynamic buffer with PostGIS the following view is working:

```
CREATE VIEW buffer500m AS
SELECT gid, st_buffer(geom,500)::geometry(polygon,31492) AS geom
FROM point;
```

Unfortunately this query gives an error using a SpatiaLite database (unrecognized token: ":").

So I've tried

```
   CREATE VIEW buffer500m AS
   SELECT gid, st_buffer(geom,500) AS geom
   FROM point;
```

and

```
   CREATE VIEW buffer500m AS
   SELECT gid, buffer(geom,500) AS geom
   FROM point;
```

but with both queries the geometry and the CRS are missing in the view. Can anyone help me?

Comment: IIUC a spatial view in Spatialite must have a real, existing geometry column, not something that's created in the query.

Answer (score 2):

Accordingly to [Spatialite coockbook](http://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite-2.4.0-4/spatialite-cookbook/html/sp-view.html) you must register your VIEW into the `views_geometry_columns`, so to make it become a real Spatial View, i.e.:

```
INSERT INTO views_geometry_columns
    (view_name, view_geometry, view_rowid, f_table_name, f_geometry_column)
  VALUES ('buffer500m', 'geometry', 'ROWID', 'point', 'geom');
```

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't working. There is still no geometry in the geom column.

Answer (score 2):

Try register your VIEW this manner:

```
INSERT INTO views_geometry_columns
    (view_name, view_geometry, view_rowid, f_table_name, f_geometry_column, read_only)
  VALUES ('buffer500m', 'geometry', 'ROWID', 'point', 'geom', 1);
```

read_only option boolean 1 for read only VIEW - read_only option boolean 0 for updatable VIEW.

In [Spatialite Cookbook](http://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite-2.4.0-4/spatialite-cookbook/html/sp-view.html)  not consign this option.